# Artifactory the web interface is not accessible

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I'm new to docker and I want to run Artifactory as a container, so I followed the steps in the official documentation. The problem is that I can't access Artifactory Web UI, I get an error from Chrome telling me that the address is not accessible.

By the way I use docker-compose, so here is my `artifactory-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  artifactory:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
    container_name: artifactory
    ports:
     - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
     - /home/everysens/docker/volumes/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

And when i run the `docker ps` command here is what i get :

[image: docker ps image]

If you need any more information tell me !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docker-compose example [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-docker-examples/blob/master/docker-compose/artifactory-oss.yml) they expose port 8181. So you should try to change the port instruction like this:

```
ports:
  - 8181:8081
```

Now point your browser to http://localhost:8181

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer :) The problem is that the two ports are in use my case. So i need to chage these. How can i proceed ?

Comment: 80 is the port that docker exposes internally. It won't conflict with anything in the host system. You can choose for example 80:8383 and point the browser to http://localhost:8383

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually after your answer i searched again, and in the docker ps command we see : 8081/tcp, so what i did in my docker-compose is putting ports as : "9090:8081" and this redirects the port of artifactory to 9090. This worked like a charm :D And your answer has a clue for that ;) Thanks again

Comment: as you corrected your answer i will mark it as that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this still relevant, but the UI port in the latest artifactory image is 8082.
I was fighting with this for a couple hours because an old docker-compose file.
It was 8081 in that file and I never mind to look inside the container until the logs spit out the port it was listening.
Best regards,
Vicente.